# How To Return all Record Entered between Two Dates(SQL)

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2008, gridview

I am Working On A winform..For Binding Values to a grid, I want to take all the records from Database which are created between two dates.
How Can i Do This
Suppose i want to return the Name,Age of all the Students Who has joined School between 01-12-2011 and 1-01-2012 ..Please help

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, Age
FROM Students
WHERE 
    DateIn >= '20111201' 
AND DateIn < '20120101'
```